# RenderDoc. a small value in Mesh Output is an approximation?

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, vertex-shader, renderdoc

## Terminology

---

In this post, I refer to this window as *Mesh Output*.
[image]

And I refer to this window as *Debug vert()*.
[image]

---

## Problem

---

I found that values of `TEXCOORD3` and `TEXCOORD4` in Mesh Output is not equal to values in Debug vert().

**Values in MeshOutput**

TEXCOORD1

```
-0.89371    0.01009     -0.44853
```

TEXCOORD2

```
0.29143    -0.74704     -0.59749
```

TEXCOORD3

```
-1.68456E-08    -1.68456E-08    -1.68456E-08    -1.68456E-08
```

TEXCOORD4

```
-7.43176E-09    -7.43176E-09    -7.43176E-09    -7.43176E-09
```

**Values in Debug vert()**

TEXCOORD1

```
-0.89371    0.01009     -0.44853
```

TEXCOORD2

```
0.29143    -0.74704     -0.59749
```

TEXCOORD3

```
 -2.98023e-08    -2.98023e-08   -2.98023e-08   -2.98023e-08
```

TEXCOORD4

```
0   0   0   0
```

---

## Question

I wonder why the values in Mesh output is not equal to the values in Debug Vert().

I guess the reason that is values in small Mesh Output are an approximation.

This guess is right?

Answer (score 0):

the vertex debugging (Debug vert())  is emulated (on the CPU), 
so it might have tiny differences to mesh output (from the GPU).

ref https://twitter.com/baldurk/status/919935224066334720